# Point source behind a diffusing plate?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I am confused about the action of a diffusion plate in optics experiments (e.g. with the Michelson interferometer). Let us say we put a point source behind a diffusion plate, what will the set up beyond the plate see? I have a couple of guesses (which are only guesses):

- It sees it as an extended source where each point produces light incoherent from every other point.
- It sees it as an extended source but each point produces light coherent with every other point.
- It still sees a point source.

Please can someone explain what the correct answer is and why.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the setup?  Then go read up on Lambertian Surfaces.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft because no where I can find gives an expansion for the role of the diffusing plate, granted many setups have it included but none with a description of what it does.

Comment: A diffusing plate diffuses!  You can easily measure the spot width on the output side by looking at it.   A good diffuser emits with near-Lambertian distribution.  End of story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replaced the diffusing plate with a lens focused on the point source, you would obviously see an extended source where every point is coherent with every other point.

A diffusing plate works, in a sense, like a very poor Fresnel lens. Light reaches each point in the diffusing plate, and at that point it has a known phase relationship with light reaching any other point on the plate. But at the plate, its direction is changed randomly. As a result, you will observe a certain intensity from that point on the plate - and the intensity will fall off as the refraction angle increases (exactly how it falls off depends on the exact properties of the surface). In the limit of the very smallest micro structure, the phase of the light is not changed by that micro-refraction, so the light from a particular point will have a certain phase relationship compared to other points on the diffuser (but at the point the light continues in a straight line...). As the grind of the diffuser becomes coarser, it gets better at diffusing the light, and the coherence information is lost.

So depending on the degree of coarseness of the diffuser, your points could all be valid; but by the time we call something a "diffuser", we usually mean the first (extended source, incoherent).